# Are "unexportable" certificates a real security measure or just security theater?

Tags: backup, windows-xp, internet-explorer, export, certificate

Recently I was working on recovering data from dead (bricked PSU) Windows XP machine, which included some client certificates installed into IE 6. I plugged in a temporary PSU and tried to export the certificate, only to be told that "these certificates are marked as non-exportable, and thus the private key can not be exported".

I've done some searching around the intertubes, however the only advices I could find were related to pre-install scenarios (ie. there is apparently an option which you can check during the installation to avoid this situation).

My questions would be:

- Is this a real security measure? It seems to me that you can simply patch the verification logic in IE6 (or the CryptoAPI) and force the export of the certificate / private-key
- Is there a ready-made tool to do this? (for backup purposes for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exporting private keys on certificates that have been marked non-exportable?  Uh, how about [a tool called Jailbreak](https://www.isecpartners.com/tools/application-security/jailbreak.aspx)...

Comment: Is this it: https://www.isecpartners.com/tools/application-security/jailbreak.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, sorry but I took my blog offline.

Comment: Link to the current version on GitHub: https://github.com/iSECPartners/jailbreak

Answer (score 1):

"Unexportable" means the private key is inaccessible to [`CryptExportKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379931%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx). It might be possible to patch CryptoAPI in memory, but I haven't found any references to it.

There also might be a way to load the registry "hive" in another system and either copy the certificates or edit the "unexportable" bit... but again, no such things on the googlenet.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

There is a new version of mimikatz that also supports CNG Export (Windows Vista / 7 / 2008 ...)

1. [download](http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/mimikatz) (and launch with administrative privileges; trunk version for last version)
2. `privilege::debug` (or not if you're already system or target only CryptoApi)
3. `crypto::patchcng` (nt 6) and/or `crypto::patchcapi` (nt 5 & 6)
4. `crypto::exportCertificates` and/or `crypto::exportCertificates CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`

pfx files are passwords protected "mimikatz"

---

Old post:

Maybe can you try another tool with other private keys functions : "mimikatz", it export other keys that other cannot export (non exportable, medium protected, orphan, etc..)
The "bit" is not altered on system file, only the program context is altered :)
For example, an user (not administrator) can export his own protected / non exportable keys without particulars rights.